# Android studio 4.0 project under android only show gradle files

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.0

android studio 4.0 project under android only shows gradle files.

[image: android studio view]

In LHS side there is only gradle file in project->android section

Comment: Did you try Invalidate Cache and Restart? And also try Build - Rebuild Project

Comment: Post screenshot of `Project` selection also.

Comment: @Shashanth I have tried both Invalided cache and restart and rebuild project. but it not work

Comment: @PratikButani in project section it show all the file and resources

Comment: Are you getting `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message? Please check it in the `Build` tab (bottom of the screen) left to the `Run` tab.

Comment: @Shashanth yes build is Successful and project run too

Comment: I have the same issue with Android Studio 4.0.1 today.

Comment: any solution? got the same problem in AS 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the `.gradle` and `.idea` folders and then rebuild

Comment: I spent 2 hours dealing with this crap. Thanks a lot for saving me a few more hours of wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve mention issue:

1.Click Edit Configurations()(Beside Build or Hammer Icon)

2.Remove unnecessary module then apply

3.Update gradle module(POPUP come when project start)

4.File->Sync Project with gradle files

5.Invalidate caches & Restart the Android Studio